# Sorting on a web-published Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, sorting, embed

I have a Google Spreadsheet that is published to the web and embedded in a website. This spreadsheet has data about hotel rooms, such as hotel name, number of rooms, date in and out, etc.

I would like to know if there is a way to allow the user to sort the data by any of the columns (sort by hotel name OR number of stars OR minimum nights, etc.).

I found an app that will pull the data and allow the user to filter it, hiding the data that doesn't match their query. I need to achieve something similar but with sorting, not filtering.

Comment: No, I switched to a completely different approach. Now I have the data in a local database and display it in the frontend as a table. Then I use a script called tablesort.js that makes any html table sortable.

Comment: Excel Online supports this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

To date, this is still not possible with Google Spreadsheets.